Como centrar un elemento en css?
Tengo el siguiente código y mi elemento no me queda en el centro.
  .letter {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
    margin left: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    min-width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block
}


Si vas a centrar horizontalmente no deberías usar margin left: 10px;

saca los margin que tengas y pon este margin: 0 auto; ya con eso se centraría solo, si le queres agregar margin top y bottom, insertalos abajo del codigo que te pase,

Desconozo tu html y si hay otro estilo que pueda estar interfiriendo pero si esa clase esta en un simple div deberia estar centrado
.letter {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 3px;
min-width: 20px;
text-align: center;

}
Con esto deberia bastar, solo con el text-align center es suficiente, no es necesario mas, quite los margin que tenias ya que uno anulaba al anterior , ademas no tiene mucho sentido a no ser que quieras centrarlo  moviendolo hacia la izquierda o algo asi.
